# angular 2 - making a modular datepicker component

Tags: angular, datepicker, transclusion

I've been reading up on transclusion and I'm trying to figure if that's what I need in order to make a popup picker service that can be dropped in anywhere.

Because ngx-bootstrap does not yet support a modal date-picker, I'm making my own.
I have multiple datepickers throughout the app, even several on the same page, so I want it to be as modular as possible.

I start with a standard date input:

```
<input 
    type="date" 
    class="form-control" 
    (click)="pickDate($event, '#requestDate')" />
```

At the moment, my datepicker is right in the page (postioned absolute, so it behaves like a popup):

```
<datepicker 
    id="requestDate" 
    name="requestDate" 
    [(ngModel)]="incident.absence.requestDate" 
    required></datepicker>
```

...  but I expect my service to generate that as-needed.

The method so far:

```
pickDate(e, popupId) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var popupCtrl = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector(popupId);
    popupCtrl.style.display= 'block';
}
```

There's going to be a lot of communication between input and datepicker passing the init and modified date back and forth. Presumably, [simple transclusion](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-2-transclusion-using-ng-content) isn't sufficient.

How does a service work that generates a control on my page?

(Or am I re-inventing the wheel here?)

Comment: Why not giving https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/examples a go?

Comment: Component and directive setup directive has this bonus that can be bound to an attribute then have your datepicker component either dynamically added and you can bind to many inputs or create parent component containing form input and datepicker and just in your forms insert that component it should work as a part of the form.  I built the latter works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

While you could write your own wrapper for the datepicker that sounds like more work than you need to do. It sounds like you are already using ngx-bootstrap so if you really wanted a custom datepicker I would just put the date picker in the dropdown or tooltip control they provide.

Realistically, I would use the datepicker from primeng: https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/calendar

It shouldn't matter much that you are using multiple ui frameworks (primeng and ngx-bootstrap) because most bloat should be shaken out in your prod build.

Comment: No, the OP says: 'Because ngx-bootstrap does not yet support a modal date-picker, I'm making my own.'

Comment: Right. I'd prefer to *not* have to make my own, but may have to.